# How big can i make the "world"/animation set?

Tags: world

I am setting up an animation scene that needs to be a sprawling area.  I have noticed that navigation gets awkward as I get further away from the central grid, especially in "user perspective".  I am only at the point of setting up the main parts now and I would like to know now if I am doing something wrong before I get into adding the details.  Is there a limit to how large I can make the world/set?  Can I extend the outer boundaries?  Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can technically make the scene infinitely as large as everything scales linearly. as you start getting up to a large scale you might start running into clipping issues with the camera however this can be adjusted by adjusting the end clip of the view.

[image]

However it's not recommended to scale things up more than needed as translation and scaling starts to get a little weird especially when you add cameras to the mix.